# I want the DC voltmeter to read 25 V. How do I adjust the value in the circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, zener, bridge

I want the voltmeter to read 25 V across the capacitor and zener diode. How do I modify this circuit?

What additional adjustments do I need to make?

[image]

Comment: You need to show the readings that it currently produces

Comment: Connect a 25 V DC source in parallel with it?

Comment: The voltmeter across the capacitor will read a different voltage than the voltmeter across the zener.

Answer (score 1):

Remove D1  and R2 and short R1, then apply 17.7V RMS to the transformer (assuming ideal diodes and 1:1 transformer ratio).

Answer (score 1):

Move R1 to the left of C1 (i.e. between the bridge rectifier and the capacitor).  That way, the voltages across C1 and D1 will be the same.

Obviously, you need a 25V zener.

Answer (score 1):

The circuit is a full wave bridge rectifier with filter capacitor feeding a Zener diode and a 100\$\Omega\$ load through a 100\$\Omega\$ series resistor.

As others pointed out, you can't have the capacitor voltage and voltage across the Zener be the same unless you move the cap to the other side of R1, that said...

The Zener diode shown is rated at 110 V, so for 25 V it wouldn't conduct and would not have any effect. You could change it to a 25 V Zener, but you would need to have the other components be the correct values as well.

The series resistor R1 has to drop whatever difference there is between the rectifier output voltage and the Zener voltage, so if the circuit was originally designed as a 110 V supply that's going to be quite a bit of voltage. Suppose the rectifier output was 125 V, with the 110 V Zener the resistor would need to drop 15 V, and it's power dissipation would be

$$
\frac{15V^2}{100\Omega} = 2.25 W 
$$
Using a 25 V Zener the resistor would drop 100 V and the dissipation would be
$$
\frac{100V^2}{100\Omega} = 100 W 
$$
That's going to be a very hot resistor.
You would need to reduce the transformer voltage to something that would be more in line with a 25 V output.

You also have to take the load into consideration, with both the series and load resistances being the same (100\$\Omega\$) they would form a voltage divider such that the minimum voltage at the rectifier output would need to be twice the desired output voltage or 50 V. This would make the minimum power dissipated in the series resistor
$$
\frac{25V^2}{100\Omega} = 6.25 W 
$$
The load would also dissipate that much.

With 50 V in, the Zener current should be minimal with most of the current going through the load, but if the load was disconnected the Zener would now need to dissipate 6.25 W as well.

With 50 V feeding it the Zener would only start to regulate if the load resistance increased, if it decreased the voltage would also decrease, so you would need to have the input voltage higher to keep the output at 25 V. To find the minimum input voltage you can use the voltage divider formula
$$
V_{out} = V_{in}\times\frac{R2}{R1+R2}
$$

And rearrange it as
$$
V_{in} = V_{out}\times{\frac{R1+R2}{R2}}
$$
Where R2 is the minimum load resistance.
Example, for R1 = 100\$\Omega\$, \$V_{out}\$ = 25 V and the minimum load R2 is 15\$\Omega\$ you would have
$$
V_{in} = 25 V\times\frac{100\Omega+15\Omega}{15\Omega} = 191.\overline{666} V
$$
and we'd be back to high power dissipation in R1 (and the Zener if the load changes). You can lower R1 so that you can use a lower input voltage, but this raises the power requirements of the Zener, everything becomes a trade-off.

This is why we tend to only use Zeners when the load current is low and relatively constant, and series pass voltage regulators or better yet switching regulators for anything else.